# u8glib - 8 Bit Embedded Systems

Tags: 64-bit, embedded

u8glib - is described as graphic library for "8 bit embedded system"

In the main page: https://code.google.com/p/u8glib/

It is described as compiled for Arduino, AVR and ARM.
I would like to ask: Does it mean it can only work on 8-bit processor, i.e. I can't compile it for 32-bit or 64-bit architecture ? If yes - how did it compile for ARM (Is there any arm processor of 8-bit architecture) ?

Answer (score 0):

Its worth going a little deeper into the site.

Firstly, arm is *always* 32 bit or better - looking up the microprocessor they mentioned, its a [32 bit cortex m0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Chips). Apparently [there's also an option to run it under SDL](http://www.imaginaryindustries.com/blog/?p=435) for debugging in linux, so yes, the library might work on a general purpose system.

Its however worth considering what this is for. Being run on *resource limited* systems to power specific LCD models. There are probably other options for full sized systems that may be easier.